# Ubuntu Server won't recognize iPhone in /media

Tags: iphone

I cant seem to mount iPhone, Ubuntu recognizes it but I am unable to locate it in /media.

```
`Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.734][3] Enabled exit on SIGUSR1 if no devices are attached. Start a new instance with "--exit" to trigger.
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4632.365909] ipheth 2-3:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.735][3] Connected to v2.0 device 1 on location 0x20005 with serial number 
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4632.370824] ipheth 2-3:4.2 enp0s29f7u3c4i2: renamed from eth2
root@UServer:/media#  tail -f /var/log/syslog
Aug 14 18:33:23 UServer usbmuxd[3738]: [18:33:23.553][3] Initialization complete
Aug 14 18:33:23 UServer usbmuxd[3738]: [18:33:23.553][3] Enabled exit on SIGUSR1 if no devices are attached. Start a new instance with "--exit" to trigger.
Aug 14 18:33:23 UServer usbmuxd[3738]: [18:33:23.553][3] Connected to v2.0 device 1 on location 0x20004 with serial number 
Aug 14 18:33:23 UServer kernel: [ 4262.184276] ipheth 2-3:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
Aug 14 18:33:23 UServer kernel: [ 4262.189278] ipheth 2-3:4.2 enp0s29f7u3c4i2: renamed from eth2
Aug 14 18:37:42 UServer kernel: [ 4521.623314] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
Aug 14 18:37:42 UServer usbmuxd[3738]: [18:37:42.992][3] Removed device 1 on location 0x20004
Aug 14 18:37:43 UServer usbmuxd[3738]: [18:37:43.012][3] usbmuxd shutting down
Aug 14 18:37:43 UServer kernel: [ 4521.644076] ipheth 2-3:4.2: Apple iPhone      USB Ethernet now disconnected
Aug 14 18:37:43 UServer usbmuxd[3738]: [18:37:43.113][3] Shutdown complete
Aug 14 18:39:32 UServer kernel: [ 4631.600018] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4631.733989] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4631.733994] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4631.733998] usb 2-3: Product: iPhone
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4631.734002] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4631.734005] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 6
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer systemd[1]: Started Socket daemon for the usbmux protocol used by Apple devices.
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.133][3] usbmuxd v1.1.0 starting up
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.134][3] Successfully dropped privileges to 'usbmux'
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.138][3] Could not get old configuration descriptor for device 2-5: -5
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.734][3] Connecting to new device on location 0x20005 as ID 1
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.734][3] Initialization complete
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.734][3] Enabled exit on SIGUSR1 if no devices are attached. Start a new instance with "--exit" to trigger.
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4632.365909] ipheth 2-3:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer usbmuxd[3859]: [18:39:33.735][3] Connected to v2.0 device 1 on location 0x20005 with serial number 
Aug 14 18:39:33 UServer kernel: [ 4632.370824] ipheth 2-3:4.2 enp0s29f7u3c4i2: renamed from eth2
```

`

So I know it knows it there but I still cannot find it in /media. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that nobody has written any "udev" rules, to automount idevices yet.

The following commands will do this for you manually:

# mkdir /media/iphone

# chown ${USER}:${USER} /media/iphone

# chmod 775 /media/iphone

# /usr/bin/idevicepair -u `/usr/bin/idevice_id -l` pair

# ifuse /media/iphone -u `/usr/bin/idevice_id -l`

You can unmount "/media/iphone" via the following:

# umount /media/iphone